# Compress to Impress

Tags: string, code-challenge, binary, compression, encoding

Inspired by both the [challenge "Unique is Cheap"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/127261/unique-is-cheap) by [*@Laikoni*](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56433/laikoni), where the score is based on the challenge itself, as well as the [JavaScript (ES6) answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/154424/52210) of [*@ETHproductions*](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42545/ethproductions) for the ["Palindrome Compression" challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/154339/palindrome-compression), where he uses a pretty cool compression method for the palindrome-flag, upper/lower case indication, and letters.

## Challenge:

You will create two programs/function: a compress program/function, and a decompress program/function.

#### Compress program/function:

Given the characters used in your own source code (both the compress and decompress source code combined) as only possible input, use any kind of bit-compression method of your choice and output the resulting `0`s and `1`s of the bit-compression of this input.

The amount of bits (`0`s and `1`s) outputted must be as short as possible, and **this amount will be the score of your answer**.

The idea is to have a nice balance between the different kind of characters used in your own source code, the size of your programs/functions, and the type of bit-compression you've used. Or to quote [*@RobertFraser*](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20931/robert-fraser) in [this comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/154339/palindrome-compression/154424#comment377149_154424):

> This is a great example of the fundamentals of engineering. Taking a problem description, thinking about different ways to solve it, and making tradeoffs between requirements (ie how many bits to dedicate to various styles), etc

### Challenge rules:

- The compressor and decompressor program/function should be in the same programming language.
- You must provide both a compression and decompression program/function, and the amount of `0`s and `1`s your compression program outputs for both programs/functions combined (concatted) as input will be your score.
- The compression must - obviously - work for all characters used in your source code of both your compression and decompression program/function, in any order or amount. (It can have undefined behavior for any characters not in your source code.)
- Input-type doesn't necessarily have to be a string. It could also be a list/array/stream of characters, and it can be as program argument, STDIN, etc. Your call.
  Same applies to the output. Can be returned from a function or printed to STDOUT. Can be a single string, integer-array, etc.
- Your compression program must output at least one `0` or `1` (so an empty `cat` program for both the compression and decompression program isn't possible).
- Your source code may not only contain `0`s and `1`s already, excluding no-ops (to prevent programming languages that print their own source code by default, where both the compression and decompression programs can be a single `0` or `1`, and the no-ops part is to prevent this behavior with an unused comment; sorry binary-based programming languages which only use `0`s and `1`s as source code).
- Although you'll have to support an input of 0 or more of the character-pool used in your programs/functions, you don't have to support an empty input. So you can assume every input will be at least 1 character.
- A possible input can be larger than your compression and decompression sizes combined.
- If for whatever reason your compression method is order-depended and has a shorter output when your input is `DecompressionProgramCompressionProgram` instead of `CompressionProgramDecompressionProgram`, you are allowed to choose either order of concatting of your programs/function for your score.

### Example:

Let's say the compression program is `ABC`, and the decompression program is `123aBc`. For any input containing zero or more of the character-pool `123ABCab`, it should be able to correctly compress those characters to `0`s and `1`s, and be able to decompress these `0`s and `1`s back into the correct characters. Some valid example inputs for these two programs can be: `ABC123aBc` (of course); `A`; `1Ca`; `22222b1121221b`; etc.

### General rules:

- [Standard rules apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422) for your answer, so you are allowed to use STDIN/STDOUT, functions/method with the proper parameters, full programs. Your call.
- [Default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- If possible, please add a link with a test for your code.
- Also, please add an explanation if necessary.

### Example of an answer:

> ## Java 8, score 1440 bits, 180 (87 + 93) bytes
>
> Here a very bad implementation in Java 8, where each character is simply printed as 8-bit binary String.
>
> **Compression function:**
>
> Input provided as `java.util.stream.IntStream`.
>
> ```java
> s->s.forEach(c->System.out.print("".format("%8s",Long.toString(c,2)).replace(' ','0')))
> ```
>
> [Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jZCxasMwEIb3PMVhKJaofYROAcfZOhTaLBnrDooi23Jt2ejkQAl5dvcchw5d2kWc0P33fbpGnVXaD8Y1p89Jt4oI3pR1lxWAdcH4UmkD@/kKcO7tCbRoOIJjsC1S8EZ1@OLC4VYByYw7rys@KKhgNezBQT5RuiMse/@sdC10ujt8UTAd9mPAwTNHRNH83CmuHjYUJa@9qzD0PNa6SujkSUr0ZmjZRsQQJ/E6llJO2UwaxmPLpDvwJtnxF8QSfv9QctF3qEX0p0kRFT8uxSxT/NeGR184KHgdpjIebL7O7JawNa4KtZDZb1Y5AzTPtzgoT4aDgpDGIy0gm9jHfCNnnMyuEeqau4S87/g6fQM)
>
> **Decompression function:**
>
> Input provided as `String`.
>
> ```java
> s->{for(Integer i=0;i<s.length();System.out.printf("%c",i.parseInt(s.substring(i,i+=8),2)));}
> ```
>
> [Try it online.](https://tio.run/##xVPLbsIwELz3KyykSokK0W5PlVJ676FcOCIOJgRqCkkUG6QK8e1pHn6sQ6BSL5VwSOz17OzO7I6f@CQv0my3/qqSPZeSfXCRnR8YE5lKyw1PUjZrPhk75WLNkmCuSpFtmQzjevfyUD@k4kokbMYyNq3k5O28ycvgvb6@TUsmphCLVxnt02yrPoMwnn9LlR6i/KiiokZSm2D0mIzGIip4KdP6WiAjeVzJNk0gxuJp@hKOn8MwjC9V3OQrjqt9nU@nbWkdatKa2WLJw45wFiUBX8BSM71UFSAiQLuaZ/uut8i@ee1WG9Bttr8mpD0D848GTB92W8N5gICSZKgBTIyF9EJMnIt35zq94Wkvu3Mk/HQhdN2vW/NBkvQWnqnX8UE/DxhImofmR68uLw76/bpVr8O51gMoJySk/X4i1cP010H19DcQth8Go/dtrjqivfM@H1@cK9@izT@gm60fhv1A/AZI6kCqGbj@GhUcb/TMqo09NE945W@iE9UZfF9ZXPD1/5f5sZLd8D0p0vf7kL88H6HnCVsH3J/j6z7TftBh@/PcEAr@N6Dnh55ev8@Zp2uH8wM)

Comment: This is not a quine test, so can I read my source code?

Comment: @WeijunZhou Depends on what you use it for, but I probably allow it in most cases. I guess you want to read your source code and then map easy of it's characters with a look-up table, or something like that?

Comment: Yes, something similar is on my mind.

Comment: I may have missed something, but here's a possible loophole in the rules: compressor->`if input==compr_code+decompr_code then return 0 else return binary charcodes of input`, decompressor->`if input==0 then return compr_code+decompr_code else convert binary codes to characters and return them`. Final score: 1 (lowest possible). The programs won't be trivial to write, but with some tricks from quines they surely are doable.

Comment: @Leo Hmm, you're indeed right that the current rules allow such an answer (unintentionally of course). Not sure how to fix it, though.. I could state you must provide the mapping you've used for each individual character, which must correspond / be the same for the compressor + decompressor input as well as any random configuration of these characters. But in that case I might limit possible answers who want to compress pairs of characters, or whatever they come up with. Any suggestions on a rule to close this loop hole, but still leave some flexibility for creativity?..

Comment: One possibility is requiring that adding a character to any input should increase the length of the compressed output by no more than 8 bits. But beware that even this change could invalidate some "honest" answers

Answer (score 2):

## Jelly, score 350, 39 + 30 = 69 bytes

## Compressor: [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 39 bytes

```
“iÐ€;⁴⁾¤8Bz0ZUṖFs5Ḅị”;⁾“”¤iÐ€;⁴BUz0ZUṖF
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5zMwxMeNa2xftS45VHjvkNLLJyqDKJCH@6c5lZs@nBHy8Pd3Y8a5gJl9wGVAlmHliDUO4XClP6nmkkIpSQbBwA)

## Decompressor: [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 30 bytes

```
s5Ḅị“iÐ€;⁴⁾¤8Bz0ZUṖFs5Ḅị”;⁾“”¤
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7/Y9OGOloe7ux81zMk8POFR0xrrR41bHjXuO7TEwqnKICr04c5pbgg1c4Gy@4BKgaxDS/7//x9tqKNgoKMAIdGQIQ42hGuIW8oAVdYQQ6Mhbo1oJmAKGuI2Fk2ZIYalhrgtxeopQ9zONiQUMobEeYqgk8gIdjyBNvgDdjQRDkwijAUA)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen whoops. fixed, thanks

Comment: @KevinCruijssen oh I'm bad lol. thanks for the fix!

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (OpenJDK 9)](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk9/), score 702 bits, 88 (42 + 46) bytes

### Compressor, 42 bytes

```java
$->new java.math.BigInteger($).toString(2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY49a8MwEIZ3/4obMkglOUK2kjbQDIUOmTIaDxdHVeTqC@mcYkp@uyvHhW6FTgd3z/u819GVViEq350/HkfjYkgMXVliz8bie@9bNsHjw7ZqLeUMBzIeviqA2J@saSEzcRnXYM7gyk0cORmv6wYo6SzvKMDrj@fpNLCqm@UM7aANLiaVc0jwPC5WO68@53ZHfMG90W@elVZJLCRymFNiI8ft3XocMiuHoWeM5cLWi18hUox2ENMX9bpBrXhfurOQUk7pW3Ub/9H4J7ncTOykf0mJBiG/AQ)

### Decompressor, 46 bytes

```java
$->new java.math.BigInteger($,2).toByteArray()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##5VGxTsMwEN3zFR46JKi1zmyoUIkOSAxMHaMObmqCQ2JbtlMUoX57iJM6NgW@ACuKc@/evXt3qeiJrqRiojq@3/W8UVJbVA0gbi2v8WsrCsulwDfrpKipMeiFcoE@E4RUe6h5gYyldrhOkh9RM@TSndVclPkeUV2abKQi9HTRuZ@yy0NnWb7foCMrZKM0M0Zq9NAvVhvBPqb@DbVveMvLZ2FZyXS6WN5m2MrtUPmoNe3SrF@P2rvOWNZg2VqsBnFbi9SJTJ3SuAOmStVd6ozlsM@yzAmck3PfE4DhcS9C3BdxB8bgcrvUGEwAjGckX/Iw50MMoX6ixjxfHyCYy4gvBs/1MYmwyBeE3rFY0J/n@@4r@CDRMAEn137CPnwzmI3E@v9mn@T3@f/Yr/dDyJVvIPDTfLR/j8/6EP7nFw)

Comment: Sorry, I'm playing the low byte-cost (*hum*, for Java, I mean) rather than the hard compression :S

Comment: Didn't even knew it was possible to put any `String` in the `BigInteger` constructor.. Figured it would give a NumberFormatException or something.. I did knew about the `.toString(2)`. Nice golf of my example answer I guess. ;)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Indeed, as it currently is, it's more a golf of your example than anything else. 703 bits means 88 bytes. I couldn't compress anything in less than 88 bytes so far, but I'm still trying to ;-)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), score 179 bits, 9+10=19 [bytes](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt/wiki/Codepage)

Compressor:

```
←6!58*-Ĩɓ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//UdsEM0VTCy3dIytOTkbjAjlGR1ZA@A93TgEA)

Decompressor:

```
←2Ĩ6!58*-Ṕ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//UdsEoyMrzBRNLbR0H@6c8v@/oaGBgYEhCIEYBoZAviGYMIAShgZQAiIHUW0AU2VoCONBNcNNg@gzNISbYGgA1w4Tg5sP1wE13gBmO5SBcB6Q5gIA)

Comment: Decompressor still seems to throw an error

Comment: That's strange. It works when I run it locally.